# Want to create a list from column of strings

Tags: python-3.x, split, strip

I take a string paragraph as input then use `rstrip()` to strip it into rows, then split() to strip each row into words.

So I'm left with a column of strings:

Barry
Sally
Andrew
Jonathan
...

How can I create a list from this output?

(I want this as output) => `['Barry', 'Sally', 'Andrew', 'Jonathan', ...]`

```
file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
file_holder = open(file_name)
```

for line in file_holder:

```
 # strip into rows
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith("From "): continue
    # strip into words
    words = line.split()
    email_list = words[1]
    print(email_list)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

```
...
words = line.split()
print(words)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that just creates n-number of lists - one for each row of text.

Comment: I have a column of strings - in Excel parlance ... I have say names:  Sally is in A1;  Peter is in A2, Jeremy is in A3, ...

Comment: So I want to take each of those names and create:  ['Sally', 'Peter', 'Jeremy', ...]

Comment: The above code returns the list of 3 items if you give a string containing 3 words, not 3 separate lists.